# How to parameterize @Scheduled(fixedDelay) with Spring 3.0 expression language?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations, scheduling

When using the Spring 3.0 capability to annotate a scheduled task, I would like to set the `fixedDelay` as parameter from my configuration file, instead of hard-wiring it into my task class, like currently...

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void readLog() {
        ...
}
```

Unfortunately it seems that with the means of the Spring Expression Language (SpEL) `@Value` returns a String object which in turn is not able to be auto-boxed to a long value as required by the `fixedDelay` parameter.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I guess the `@Scheduled` annotation is out of question. So maybe a solution for you would be to use `task-scheduled` XML configuration. Let's consider this example (copied from [Spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)):

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="someObject" method="readLog" 
               fixed-rate="#{YourConfigurationBean.stringValue}"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

... or if the cast from String to Long didn't work, something like this would:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="someObject" method="readLog"
            fixed-rate="#{T(java.lang.Long).valueOf(YourConfigurationBean.stringValue)}"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Again, I haven't tried any of these setups, but I hope it might help you a bit.

Comment: Thanks, the XML configuration did the trick. I am bit surprised that the annotation seems so bound to string values, anyways, I go with the  old-school way ;-)

Comment: Is there any Java equivalent for above config?

Comment: @Grzegorz Oledzki what will be the value of "someObject" under <task:scheduled > tag. If a controller have more than one method that needs fixed delay and initial delay then how will that be handled?

Answer (score 488):

Spring v3.2.2 has added String parameters to the original 3 long parameters to handle this. `fixedDelayString`, `fixedRateString` and `initialDelayString` are now available too.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${my.fixed.delay.prop}")
public void readLog() {
        ...
}
```

Comment: @Avi This answer comes three years after the OP's question. At the time of the question (and accepted answer) this feature didn't exist.

Comment: @medveshonok117 and? it is still the most correct answer now.

Comment: In Kotlin you need to escape the $ in the String:
"\${my.fixed.delay.prop}"

Answer (score 54):

You can use the `@Scheduled` annotation, but together with the `cron` parameter only:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${yourConfiguration.cronExpression}")
```

Your 5 seconds interval could be expressed as `"*/5 * * * * *"`. However as I understand you cannot provide less than 1 second precision.

Comment: The cron expression that you have shown is equivalent to fixedRate, which is different to fixedDelay

Answer (score 16):

In Spring Boot 2, we can use Spring Expression Language (SpPL) for `@Scheduled` annotation properties:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${fixed-rate.in.milliseconds}")
public void fixedRate() {
    // do something here
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${fixed-delay.in.milliseconds}")
public void fixedDelay() {
    // do something here
}

@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
public void cronExpression() {
    // do something here
}
```

The `application.properties` file will look like this:

```
fixed-rate.in.milliseconds=5000
fixed-delay.in.milliseconds=4000
cron.expression=0 15 5 * * FRI
```

That's it. Here is [an article](https://attacomsian.com/blog/task-scheduling-spring-boot) that explains task scheduling in detail.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can convert the value yourself by defining a bean. *I haven't tried that*, but I guess the approach similar to the following might be useful for you:

```
<bean id="FixedDelayLongValue" class="java.lang.Long"
      factory-method="valueOf">
    <constructor-arg value="#{YourConfigurationBean.stringValue}"/>
</bean>
```

where:

```
<bean id="YourConfigurationBean" class="...">
         <property name="stringValue" value="5000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like one way, but to be honest I was hoping for a more elegant ("springish") solution :-)

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work, since the @Scheduled annotation attribute fixedDelay requires a (long) constant to be assigned.

Comment: Ah, that's right. So I guess you can't do it with the `@Scheduled` annotation then.

Answer (score 0):

In case of delay configured as Duration, e.g. `5s`, there are not pretty, but working solution from [issues: support flexible duration parsing in placeholders](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15126)

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = 
   "#{T(org.springframework.boot.convert.DurationStyle).detectAndParse('${app.update-cache}')}")
```

I do not understand, why issue is closed and Duration is not realized yet
BTW: I've tried, but without success, a little more pretty:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "'PT'+'${app.update-cache}'") and
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "'PT'.concat('${app.update-cache}')
```