# How to use Java Constant as a part of @Scheduler expression annotation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, constants

I am using Spring scheduler as given bellow.

```
 @Scheduled(fixedDelay = ((10 * 60 * 1000) / 2))
    public void runDynamic()
    {
      //doing my stuff
    }
```

Now suppose I have one constant like this

```
public static final Integer VARIANCE_TIME_IN_MIN = 10;
```

And I want to use this constant as a part of my expression something like this :

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = ((MyConstants.VARIANCE_TIME_IN_MIN * 60 * 1000) / 2))
public void runDynamic()
{
//doing my stuff
}
```

but it is giving my compile time error. Any ideas? Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16463403/106261

Comment: Hi @NimChimpsky, Thanks for your reply, but I cannot find any example using Java Constant in your given link. Is it impossible ?

Comment: Could you please post the compile time error as well?

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java annotations take compile time constants, which are defined as final primitives or strings.

SO change your definition to

```
   public static final int VARIANCE_TIME = 10;
   public static final long FIXED_DELAY = ((VARIANCE_TIME * 60 * 1000) / 2)

   @Scheduled(fixedDelay = FIXED_DELAY)
   public void runDynamic()
```

Comment: why need another extra bracket?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Task scheduling using cron expression from properties file**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${cronTrigger.expression}")
public void runDynamic()
    {
      //doing my stuff
    }
```

**Config in XML File:**

```
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="exampleJob" />
    <!-- run every morning at 6 AM -->
    <property name="expression" value="0 0 6 * * ?" />
</bean>
```

This [link1](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/23/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/) and [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) might help you

You can also create the Tash Scheduler dynamically(programatically) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630539/scheduling-a-job-with-spring-programmitically-with-a-fixedrate-set-from-a-databa/14632758#14632758)

Comment: but it's from property file, not from Java Constant.

Comment: You cannot schedule a task through Java constants.
Why do you need to use this constant? can't you reuse ${cronTrigger.expression} itself!!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final long VARIANCE_TIME_IN_MIN = 10l;

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = ((VARIANCE_TIME_IN_MIN * 60 * 1000) / 2))
public void runDynamic() {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: could've also explained that you changed the type to long, as it's not easily visible

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.