# Error while using parameter in @Scheduled in a spring 4.1 application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-el, spring-4

I have `Spring 4.1 Application`. I am trying to schedule based on value from property file. I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598712/how-to-parameterize-scheduledfixeddelay-with-spring-3-0-expression-language). But I do not want the following way of EL inside `@Scheduled`

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${my.fixed.delay.prop}")
public void readLog() {
        ...
}
```

Here is my class.

```
public class MyService {

    @Value("${timerInMilliSeconds: 60000}")
    private long timerinMilliSeconds;

     public myService(){

     }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = timerinMilliSeconds)
        public void myTimer() {
            //do stuff
        }

}
```

I get this error.

`The value for annotation attribute Scheduled.fixedRate must be a constant 
 expression`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that; it's a limitation of the way annotations work - Strings in annotations have to be constants (they are stored in the class and can't be different for each instance).

By the way `${my.fixed.delay.prop}` is not "EL", it's a property placeholder.