# Configure Spring task scheduler to run at a fixeDelay or run at once based on a boolean

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have a code which runs at a regular interval.
Below is code for that

```
@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class Cer {

    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${xvc}")
    public void getData() {
        getCat();
        getB();
        return;
    }
}
```

I want to change`@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${xvc}")` this based on a boolean say `runOnce` if runOnce is true @scheduled should run once only say on code startup.
Any advice how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your version of Spring ? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598712/how-to-parameterize-scheduledfixeddelay-with-spring-3-0-expression-language.

Comment: using spring boot version 1.2.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

I would place the functionality that you want to schedule in a component:

```
@Component
public class ServiceToSchedule {

    public void methodThatWillBeScheduled() {
        // whatever
        return;
    }
}
```

And have two additional components that will be instantiated depending on a `Profile`. One of them schedules the task, and the other one just executes it once.

```
@Profile("!scheduled")
@Component
public class OnceExecutor {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceToSchedule service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void executeOnce() {
        // will just be execute once
        service.methodThatWillBeScheduled();
    }
}


@Profile("scheduled")
@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledExecutor {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceToSchedule service;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = whateverYouDecide)
    public void schedule() {
        // will be scheduled
        service.methodThatWillBeScheduled();
    }
}
```

Depending on which profile is active, your method will be executed just once (`scheduled` profile is not active), or will be scheduled (`scheduled` profile is active).

You set the spring profiles by (for example) starting your service with:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=scheduled
```