# Inject environment variable to annotation value with Spring

Tags: java, spring

I use Spring 4.
I run Spring context like:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.scan(BASE_PACKAGE);
    context.refresh();
```

I use injecting of environment variables like:

```
@Value("#{systemEnvironment['ENV_VAR'] ?: 60}")
private int someDelay;
```

And it works pretty fine.

The question is how to make this work:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${ENV_VAR ?: 60000}")
public void runSomeTask(){
    System.out.println("hello ");
}
```

Now spring throws exception:

```
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'runSomeTask': Invalid fixedDelayString value "${ENV_VAR ?: 60000}" - cannot parse into integer
```

I suppose I need to create a BeanPostProcessor which is responsible for processing such values, but I have no idea which one exactly.

P.S. It works fine with Spring Boot out of the box.

Comment: What is wrong with `Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "("#{systemEnvironment['ENV_VAR'] ?: 60000}")`?

Comment: @Jens the same exception actually as with `"${ENV_VAR ?: 60000}"`

Comment: Can you Show the exception text

Comment: Alternatively, you can do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2602676/1654233

Comment: @Jens `Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'runSomeTask': Invalid fixedDelayString value "#{systemEnvironment['ENV_VAR'] ?: 60000}" - cannot parse into integer`

Comment: It's not possible

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

> **#{'${ENV_VAR}' == null ? '60000' : '${ENV_VAR}' }**