# Java EE 7 schedule tasks in different environments/tiers

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler, java-ee-7

Is there a way to configure a specific scheduled task in different environments and schedules?
E.g. The same scheduled task 'MyTask' is supposed to run in Integration and Production. In Production 'MyTask' has to run every 24h and in Integration 'MyTask' must not run at all.
Currently we're focusing on the native Java EE 7 schedule mechanism. Spring, Quartz are additional frameworks/libraries which we don't want to use (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring try `@Scheduled("${cronEx}")`. You can provide for each environment a different configuration defining the cronEx-value. For example you could get the cronEx-value via JNDI. More about it: [SO-Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598712/how-to-parameterize-scheduledfixeddelay-with-spring-3-0-expression-language#16463403) and [SO-Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183321/how-to-use-jndi-datasource-provided-by-tomcat-in-spring).

If you need something more sophisticated have a look at the QUARTZ project: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ It is a library to schedule jobs.

Comment: Currently we're focusing on the native java EE 7 schedule mechanism. 
Spring, Quartz are additional frameworks/libraries which we don't want to use (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of creating a scheduled task in Java EE. I think that what fits better for you is using **ManagedScheduledExecutorService**.

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class PeriodicTask {

    @Resource
    ManagedScheduledExecutorService mses;

    @Inject
    @Config("period")
    private int period;

    public void startJobs() {
        mses.scheduleAtFixedRate(this::task, 0, period, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    private void task() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

That way you can, for instance, inject the config value **period** depending on the running environment. If you don't need to schedule a task for an specific environment you can have another configuration parameter to avoid calling **scheduleAtFixedRate** method.

The only thing pending to do is calling **startJobs** method.